# Update não atualiza

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, crud

O app funciona assim: Um SMS é recebido, então o app verifica se o número que enviou este SMS está cadastrado, caso esteja o app verifica os vinte primeiros caracteres da mensagem, qual chamo de texto (exemplo: Luz 1...............-LIG , ou: Luz 1...............-DSL). Se esse texto existir então o app atualiza a mensagem no banco, se não ele insere uma nova mensagem. O problema está na hora de fazer Update, não da erro na execução, contudo não atualiza. abaixo o update:

```
public Long atualiza (ReceiveOne receiveOne) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();

    valores.put(RECEIVE_ONE_DATA, receiveOne.getReceiveOne());

    return (long) db.update(RECEIVE_ONE_NAME, valores, RECEIVE_ONE_KEY + " =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(receiveOne.getId())});

}
```

e abaixo o código que chama o método:

```
receiveOne.setReceiveOne(smsBody.toString());

receiveOne.setId(db.questTextReceiverOne(smsBody));

db.atualiza(receiveOne);
```

O `smsBody` é o SMS recebido. o método `questTextReceiverOne()` verifica a existência do texto e retorna o id.

Testei vários métodos update e da na mesma.

```
id = 0. //retorno do atualiza = 0

db = SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.usuario.infinium8/databases/SMS.
```

No banco de dados estou com apenas uma mensagem. A mensagem existente é: led 1...............-LIG ai chega o SMS : led 1...............-DSL, como o texto led 1 - é igual ao que está no banco a mensagem vai para o update.

o método atualiza está num *SQLiteOpenHelper* e é chamado num `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: O método `db.update()` retorna o número de registos actualizados, zero indica que nenhum foi. Para actualizar um registo terá de passar um `id` que exista na DB. Verifique se `receiveOne.getId()` retorna um `id` existente.

Comment: Ta certo, preciso então fazer com que o questTextReceiverOne(); que está retornando o indice da lista me retorne o id. Tentei fazer um list.get(numero do dado na lista) que nem faço com o delete.

Comment: Assim, para fazer este processo por um button é simples, neste caso quero que ocorra quando o SMS chegue e ai que ta, não consigo puxa o id, nem pelo getId(), so consigo fazer isso no retorno do insert.

Comment: Se o nome (Led 1) for único faça o *update* usando o nome em vez do id.

Comment: hmmm.. mas como vou usar o nome no update?

Comment: Seria qualquer coisa assim: `return (long) db.update(RECEIVE_ONE_NAME, valores, RECEIVE_ONE_NomeDoCampoNome + " =?", new String[]{receiveOne.getNome()});`

Comment: AAAAAEE, fiz um método que você entra com a String e ela retorna o id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a resposta foi criar um método em que entro com o sms recebido, ele verifica o texto e retorna o objeto do banco:

```
public ReceiveOne quest_IdReceiverOne (String message) {

    int size = receiveOneSize();

    List<ReceiveOne> list = selectReceiverOne();

    ReceiveOne receiveOne = new ReceiveOne();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        String data = String.valueOf(list.get(i));

        if (data.substring(0, 19).equals(message.substring(0, 19)))
            return receiveOne = list.get(i);
    }

    return null;

}
```